# Changing the rendering mechanism of all windows text-boxes system-wide

Tags: c++, c, winapi, textbox, operating-system

I need to write a novel and customized algorithm for handling and rendering right-to-left and left-to-right pieces of strings in a text-box, and then I need to make all text-boxes in windows, to use this algorithm.

My question is about the second job, that is, how can I change the rendering mechanism of all the text-boxes in a windows machine? From which part of Win32 API should I start? Is it some kind of hacking existing system dlls or there's some API for doing such things?

Comment: For Windows, where about 90% of all apps use a custom UI without the WinAPI, this won't work. If you really want this you might try Mac OS X if you can, but I think the problem there is that you can't simply change system behavior without the password of an administrator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever you do, you will never cover all programs with this! If a program uses its own toolkit, or a toolkit not using Win32 built in widgets, any hacks on the Win32 API will have no effect.

Tinkering with the Win32 API is possible by injecting a DLL in every process, that hooks into Win32 API calls through debugging mechanisms. Technically this means you'll have to reimplement the whole parts of the Win32 API which behaviour you'd like to alter. Also these kinds of methods are also used by malware software, so antivirus programs will go haywire.

In conclusion: Doing this is a huge effort, error prone, will never cover all applications and causes serious problems.

Comment: Thanks; so I deduce that creating components with the same functionality for all possible frameworks (Win32, Qt, Gtk, Wx-widgets, java, ...) is a better solution.